# Remove single slash but not double slash from string using sed

Tags: bash, sed

the string I want to edit looks like this:

```
/word1 /word2 //word3
```

wanted output:

```
word1 word2 //word3
```

The following command deletes all slashes and it makes since it does so

```sh
str=`echo $str | sed -r 's/\///g'`
```

How do I delete only single slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
str=$(sed -E 's~(/{2,})|/~\1~g' <<< "$str")
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/zP1Q7q):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='/word1 /word2 //word3'
sed -E 's~(/{2,})|/~\1~g' <<< "$s"
# => word1 word2 //word3
```

Note the `-E` option (as `-r` option) enables the POSIX ERE regex syntax. `'s~(/{2,})|/~\1~g'` matches and captures two or more consecutive slashes into Group 1 or only matches a single slash otherwise, and replaces the matches with the contents of Group 1 (thus, restoring multiple slashes in the output, only removing single ones).

If you want to *replace single slashes with a space*, you can use the following GNU `sed`:

```sh
perl -pe 's~(?<!/)/(?!/)~ ~g' <<< "$s"
## or
sed -E 's~(^|[^/])/($|[^/])~\1\n\2~g;s//\1\n\2/g;s/\n/ /g' <<< "$s"
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/GknOWl).

The `perl` command matches any `/` chars that are not immediately preceded (`(?<!/)`) nor followed (`(?!/)`) with a slash. The `sed` command preprocesses all single slashes (`(^|[^/])/($|[^/])` matches and captures start of string or a non-slash char into Group 1, then matches a `/` and then captures end of string or a non-slash into Group 2), and replaces with Group 1 + newline + Group 2 values, i.e. isolates the single slashes by turning them into newlines, and then these newlines (as they never appear in the pattern space) are replaced with whatever you need (here, a space).

Comment: Thanks you it worked, but I have a question, which part of the syntax is exactly responisble for replacing the single slash? /~\1~g' ?
also if i want to do the same but instead of deleting the single slash I want to replace it with a space, what would the comment look like

Comment: @AbdulrahmanTarek You asked to *remove* the single slash, not *replace* with another string/char, hence my solution looks like this. Use `perl` to replace single slashes, `str=$(perl -pe 's~(?<!/)/(?!/)~ ~g' <<< "$str")`

Comment: Perhaps use the less noisy idiom `//+` for two or more `/`'s

Comment: @potong However, `{2,}` is more customizable.